# How to catch menu opened change in menu bar?

Tags: vaadin, menubar

In vaadin 14, we can use addOpenedChangeListener to catch if a ComboBox drop down is opened or closed. Is there any way to catch if a menu (in MenuBar) is opened or closed?

Thanks you in advance.